# Passing image as props to styled components in Next.js

Tags: next.js, styled-components

I'm trying to pass an image to set as my background in Next whit Styled Components but causes an unexpected behavior.

Hero Component:

```js
import djEventImg from '@/public/images/dj-event.jpg'
import { Hero } from './ShowCase.styles'

const ShowCase = () => {
  return <Hero image={djEventImg}></Hero>
}

export default ShowCase
```

Styled Component:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const Hero = styled.div`
  // background image props
  background-image: url(${(props) => props.image});
  width: 100;
  height: 300px;
`
```

Comment: _"but causes an unexpected behavior"_ ... What unexpected behavior? Please add the issue related text to the question. PS: Most probably you need to pass `djEventImg.src` instead. Also, the images stored in `public` directory can be directly served. [ [Ref.](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) ] So you don't even need to import the image --- `<Hero image="/images/dj-event.jpg" />`

Comment: Simple like that, I get this in HTML `url(src:/_next/static/image/src/public/images/dj-event.d431960f340929359ffb5934fc6d628a.jpg;height:851px;width:1280px;blur-data-u-r-l:/_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fimage%2Fsrc%2Fpublic%2Fimages%2Fdj-event.d431960f340929359ffb5934fc6d628a.jpg&w=8&q=70;)`

Comment: @RicardodePaula Have you tried `<Hero image="/images/dj-event.jpg" />` as suggested? Does it work for you?

Comment: I have this ` background-image: url(/images/dj-event.jpg)` in Html, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Last part of my initial comment may not be valid for you. Looking at your generated CSS, I believe you have `public` inside your `src` folder [(so static file serving from there won't work)](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/src-directory#caveats). Try this instead: `<Hero image={djEventImg.src} />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I replicated your code in my local mashine and got an image with this code

*Hero Component:*

```
import djEventImg from '/public/images/dj-event.jpg'
import { Hero } from './ShowCase.styles'

const ShowCase = () => {
  return <Hero image={djEventImg}></Hero>
}

export default ShowCase
```

*Styled Component:*

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const Hero = styled.div`
  background-image: url(${props => props.image.src});
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
`;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's my first Next project. In ReactJS I never needed to put the .src at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can import Icon directly to your styled-component. See following answer:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Image from "./yourImage.png";

export const Hero = styled.div`
  // background image props
  background-image: url(${Image.src});
  width: 100;
  height: 300px;
`
```